# conditional data-binding - knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am making an `li` tag. And on one of the `li` tag, I want it to be formed only when it contains a certain value.
In HTML, not javascript.

This is the code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
    <li><a data-bind="text:orgChart().category[0].Name, attr: { href: category[0].Name.url }"></a></li>
    <li data-bind="text:orgChart().Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to form the second `li` tag only if the `orgChart().category[0].Name` has certain value. Else only two `li` tags will be formed.

Comment: you mean you want to `hide` it when there is no value for second `li`

Answer (score 2):

Thats coming straight from the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element)

```
<ul>
    <li>This item always appears</li>
    <!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
        <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: so it will be, `<!-- ko if: orgChart().category[0].Name == 'sometext' -->`    is the syntax correct

Comment: Yes, if `Name` is not a observable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ["if" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Index</a></li>
    <!-- ko if: ko.unwrap(orgChart().category[0].Name)=="smth" -->
    <li><a data-bind="text:orgChart().category[0].Name, attr: { href: category[0].Name.url }"></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li data-bind="text:orgChart().Name"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this wont work you will get error `scope` issue mate